# How can I run an exe for an Electron app from within Python on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, command-line, electron

How can I run an exe for an Electron app from within Python on Windows?

Ultimately, the objective is to run a custom command line app built with Electron, passing arguments. (I use vscode as an example for reproducibility.)

This does not work:

```py
os.system(r'"C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\Code - Insiders.exe"')
# output: 1
```

These methods start the app (but not from within Python):

- Manually running "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS
  Code Insiders\Code - Insiders.exe" in the command prompt
- In Mathematica:

  ```
  Run["\"C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\\Code - Insiders.exe\""]
  ```

I also tried the following with no success:

- Other methods of executing command line instructions in Python,
  including running a batch script from Python
- Other apps built with Electron (e.g. Typora)
- A fresh Python environment

Another observation:

```
os.system(rf'start /wait cmd /k "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\Code - Insiders.exe"')
```

opens a cmd.exe window with

```
(my_conda_env) c:\my_path_to_py_proj>
```